# Proving tripartite graph is always planar

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, planar-graphs

> Consider the complete tripartite graph $K_{a,b,c}$ on $a+b+c$
>   vertices. Provide an embedding to show that $K_{1,1,n}$ is always
>   planar (for $n\geq 1$). How many faces will this graph have?

I am really not sure how to approach either part. I think I should use euler's formula for the second part, which gives $v + f - e = 2$. Here, we'd have $v = n + 2$ and so we obtain $e = n + f$. Not so sure if I can get a better value.

I will appreciate your help in solving this problem

Comment: For a planar embedding, how about putting $n$ points $v_1,\dots,v_n$ on a straight line, and putting $u$ on one side of that line and $w$ on the other side, and drawing lines from $uv_i$ and $wv_i$? As for the number of faces, I count $2(n-1)+1$.

Comment: You have overcounted the faces. Remember that the part with $n$ vertices has no edges among them.

Answer (score 3):

For the embedding, consider placing one vertex at $(-1,0)$, one at $(1,0)$, and the other $n$ along the positive $y$ axis.

You have the correct $v$, so if you compute $e=1\cdot 1+1\cdot n +1\cdot n$, you can use Euler’s formula to deduce $f$.  Or just count $f$ directly from your embedding, remembering to include the unbounded outer face.

Comment: How'd you get $e = 1 \cdot 1 + 1 \cdot n + 1 \cdot n = 2n + 1$? Does this mean $f = n + 1$?

Comment: The edge count is from the definition of complete tripartite. More generally, $e=ab +ac+bc$. Yes, $f=n+1$.